HCL Domino http process - Waiting for Session to Finish
I'm running Domino 14.0FP2 in a test environment before deployment. We do get some web requests (mainly bots looking for Wordpress vulnerabilities which just get bounced). However every so often a request causes a thread to remain open with the CPU running at 100%. We can't even restart the HTTP process (i.e. tell http restart via the console does not complete) so we have to shut the whole server down. tell http show thread state indicates that one thread is still processing and the others are still idle e.g.:

Http Worker Thread ID [1218]: Working session [165]: Session State [Processing Request] : Client IP Address [xx.xx.xx.xx] : User Name [Anonymous] : GET /domain.nsf?Open HTTP/1.0

I've enabled HTTP logging (see KB0032210) and the HTTP process stops logging at Calling Inotes Process Request) which indicates this is where the issue may be. See the attached log excerpt:
*** End Request Step: Session 164, Thread 1218, Clock 26092000
*** Log Request: Session 164, Thread 1218, Clock 26092000

*** Start SSL Handshake: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26094391
*** Client IP Address [xx.xx.xx.xx], Server IP Address [192.168.1.xx]: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26094391
*** SSL Handshake Success: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26095250
*** New Request -- Parse and Check Request: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096547
GET /domain.nsf?Open HTTP/1.0
Host: test.ax-ea.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; NetcraftSurveyAgent/1.0; +info@netcraft.com)
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: close

*** Process Request: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096547
*** Client IP Address [xx.xx.xx.xx], Server IP Address [192.168.1.xx]: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096547

*** Start Request Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Raw Request Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Pre Authenticate Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Authenticate Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Post Authenticate Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Get Group List Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Authorized Server Access Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Translate Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Post Translate Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Authorized Step: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Process Request for User Anonymous: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Calling Url Cache Process Request: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562
*** Calling Inotes Process Request: Session 165, Thread 1218, Clock 26096562

It looks like a similar problem to this one from September 2008 and the fix appeared to be to downgrade the server to a previous version. Obviously not ideal.
Has anyone got the same issue on Domino 14.0 and if so, do you know the fix?
Thanks in advance.

I suggest that you create a support ticket with HCL

Turning persistent connections off appears to have solved this problem however it's not ideal. HCL seems to recommend this https://support.hcl-software.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0026401
